How many advancements can a Root RPG character get before running out of options to choose from in the advancement list?
Some of my players are fulfilling both of her drives every session, so I want to know how many sessions I have before I need to add some new options to choose.
The Advancement list is in the Root Core Book on the page 175

Without checking every playbook, most Vagabonds can/will have a total of 23-25 Advancements before their default peak is reached:

Increase all stats to +2

Character creation seems to provide 3/10 of the possible stats
7 Advancements


Choose up to 5 Moves from their own Playbook

Character creation seems to provide 3/5 of these selections
2 Advancements


Choose up to 2 Moves from other Playbooks

Characters begin with no 'other Playbook' Moves
2 Advancements


Choose up to a total of 7 Weapon Skills (2 at a time)

Characters seem to begin with 1 Weapon Skill
3 Advancements


Choose up to a total of 6 Roguish Feats (2 at a time)

Number of Roguish Feats varies by playbook, from 1 to 4
1 to 3 Advancements


Max all three Harm tracks at 6

Each Vagabond begins with 4 in each of the 3 harm tracks, 12/18
6 Advancements


Gain up to a total of 6 Connections (2 at a time)

Each Vagabond begins with 2/6 Connections
2 Advancements



I do not see anything 'balancing' the Playbooks with a fewer/greater number of Roguish Feats, but I'm guessing they decided it was

Root's first (on-release) supplement, Traveler's and Outsiders, adds Masteries (p69). This adds a new Advancement option (which I will split into 2 for clarity) that total 4 additional Advancements:

Master one Basic Move (max of 2)
Master up to two known Weapon Moves (max of 4)

It also provides an optional subset of rules (even more optional than including the book or not) that allows Vagabonds to spend an additional 2 Advancements choosing "Species Moves" (p60) that do not count against their Playbook Moves.
